# Codeigniter 2.0 Can not extend core library

Tags: codeigniter-2

not sure what is the problem? My class that is in Application/core folder, and here it is:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Image_lib extends CI_Image_lib {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function tesit($msg) {
        log_message('error', $msg);
    }

}
```

I get this error :

Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Image_lib::testit()

when I call it like this : $this->image_lib->testit('not working');

What I am missing, this is so strange.

Comment: Why don't you use *libraries* folder instead of core ?

Comment: @CanGeliş hi, I'm not CI guru, I have start learning it, why should I use it, when? and when core folder? What is the difference? I didn't know that their is a difference. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't play with *core* that much. *libraries* folder exists for your purpose. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: @CanGeliş I was just extending core library with simple function as a test, you answer isn't an answer. Give me example if you know? that is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the following classes are core classes all others should be extended in library folder.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

```
Benchmark
Config
Controller
Exceptions
Hooks
Input
Language
Loader
Log
Output
Router
URI
Utf8
```

Comment: aha, thank you. I didn't know that, I have miss that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Move your class to the application/library folder and it will override the one in the system folder when you call it.